# Number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length?

Tags: r, for-loop

Not sure what is wrong here.

Building the model along with the example

```
LBsPD <- c()
for (i in 1:5000) {
  FishCaught <- sample(x=c(7,4,2), size=1, prob = c(.1,.6,.3),replace = TRUE)
  YellowPercent <- sample(x=c(0,.25,.35), size=1, prob = c(.25,.5,.25),replace = TRUE)
  BluePercent <- 1-YellowPercent 
  BlueLBs <- rnorm(n=365, mean=35, sd=18)
  YellowLBs <- rnorm(n=365, mean=30, sd=18)
  LBsPerDay <- FishCaught * ((BluePercent * BlueLBs[BlueLBs > 20]) + (YellowPercent * YellowLBs[YellowLBs > 20]))
   LBsPD[i] <- LBsPerDay    
}
```

Keep getting the 50+ errors "Number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length" But in the example it is the same.

Comment: The size of the this `BlueLBs[BlueLBs > 20]` is indeterminate and is different from `YellowLBs[YellowLBs > 20]`. Adding two numeric arrays of different sizes will yield an array the size of the largest with the values of the smaller array being recycled. Perhaps you want to sum these individually then add them to get the single value you want?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a drawn-out explanation that @AndrewChisholm started.

I'll start by (1) setting the random seed, so you can repeat this in *your* console, and (2) stepping through the `for` loop's first iteration.

```r
set.seed(42) # since this is a random process
i <- 1       # first pass in the loop
FishCaught <- sample(x=c(7,4,2), size=1, prob = c(.1,.6,.3),replace = TRUE)
YellowPercent <- sample(x=c(0,.25,.35), size=1, prob = c(.25,.5,.25),replace = TRUE)
BluePercent <- 1-YellowPercent 
BlueLBs <- rnorm(n=365, mean=35, sd=18)
```

Now, let's look at the components of your next expression:

```r
# FishCaught * ((BluePercent * BlueLBs[BlueLBs > 20]) +
#   (YellowPercent * YellowLBs[YellowLBs > 20]))

str(BlueLBs[BlueLBs > 20])
#  num [1:291] 24.8 41.5 46.4 42.3 33.1 ...
str(YellowLBs[YellowLBs > 20])
#  num [1:255] 64.1 22.5 36.3 59.3 31.6 ...
```

It doesn't matter now that `BluePercent` is 1 and `YellowPercent` is 0, since `0*somevec` is still the length of the vector, so you are effectively trying to add vectors of different sizes. What does this mean to you?

```r
c(1,3,5,7,9) + c(1,1000,1)
# Warning in c(1, 3, 5, 7, 9) + c(1, 1000, 1) :
#   longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
# [1]    2 1003    6    8 1009
```

The bigger problem here is that R does **not** consider this a problem: it warns you that it is suspect, but it happily "recycles" the values for you. So this is not what is causing your error.

```r
LBsPerDay <- FishCaught * ((BluePercent * BlueLBs[BlueLBs > 20]) + (YellowPercent * YellowLBs[YellowLBs > 20]))
# Warning in (BluePercent * BlueLBs[BlueLBs > 20]) + (YellowPercent * YellowLBs[YellowLBs >  :
#   longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
str(LBsPerDay)
#  num [1:291] 174 291 325 296 232 ...
```

This is not a syntax error, but you should treat it as a "data is now corrupt" error, because you really don't know for certain what numbers were added/multiplied to other numbers (see my previous example of with `c(1,1000,1)` to see that if we think things should be aligned, then those results are going to result in some incorrect logical conclusions from this process).

Here's the real problem:

```r
LBsPD[i] <- LBsPerDay
# Warning in LBsPD[i] <- LBsPerDay :
#   number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

First, some clarification:

1. This is a `Warning`, not an `Error`. The only way I get an error with that is if I had previous set `options(warn=2)` (which, btw, is not a bad idea here). Warnings can often be ignored if you expect them, but in this case you should really pay attention to it and treat it as an error.
2. `LBsPerDay` is length 291, but you try trying to cram 291 numbers into one position in the ***vector*** `LBsPD[i]`. That is, the length of the LHS using `[i]` is always going to be the length of `i`, which is 1; whereas the length of the RHS is (in this case) 291.

Options:

1. I'm inferring that your `BlueLBs[BlueLBs > 20]` might be a filter so that fish caught below `20` (pounds? kilos? grams?) will not be "caught". In that case, let's just replace those under 20 with `0` ... but please check me on this logic ... a blue/yellow that is below 20 will be changed to 0, effectively "not caught":

   ```r
   LBsPerDay <- FishCaught * ((BluePercent * replace(BlueLBs, BlueLBs <= 20, 0)) + (YellowPercent * replace(YellowLBs, YellowLBs <= 20, 0)))
   str(LBsPerDay)
   #  num [1:365] 174 291 325 296 232 ...
   ```

   (No warning, no error.)
2. If you intend `LBsPD` to contain all of the weights for each iteration in your simulation, then start with `LBsPD <- list()`, in which case you'll eventually use

   ```r
   LBsPD <- list()
   for (i in 1:5000) {
     # ...
     LBsPD[[i]] <- LBsPerDay
   }
   ```

   where after 3 (of 5000) iterations, your `LBsPD` looks like:

   ```r
   str(LBsPD)
   # List of 3
   #  $ : num [1:365] 174 291 325 296 232 ...
   #  $ : num [1:365] 160.7 97 161.5 145 99.6 ...
   #  $ : num [1:365] 30.3 121.4 111.7 210.8 139.7 ...
   ```

BTW, you might notice that both `BlueLBs` and `YellowLBs` have negatives ... not sure if that's a problem, but negative pounds seems suspect. (Because "normal distributions" are by definition unbounded, many things labeled as "normally distributed" are typically not asymptotically compliant. For hasty simulations like this, I often revert to a triangular distribution, which may be normal-enough for some applications, and certainly never gives negative or extremely-positive weights.)